# What does "intensity of light" mean?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, terminology

In [this lecture](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-111sc-principles-of-chemical-science-fall-2014/unit-i-the-atom/lecture-3/#Lecture_Video3) from MIT, the professor defines the intensity of a wave as the square of the amplitude of the wave. But, at the same time, the professor defines the intensity of light as the number of photons per second. Are these definitions equivalent?

I know that light has both properties of a particle and properties of a wave, but the two different definitions of intensity have different units, which seems confusing to me.

Additionally, when I searched up intensity on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensity), I was unable to find a definition of intensity that matched the definition provided in the lecture. Some of the definitions of intensity that I did find on Wikipedia were "power per unit area," "power per unit solid angle," and "luminous flux per unit solid angle."

Thus, my question is: what do the terms "intensity," "intensity of light," and "intensity of a wave," mean? What are their definitions?

Comment: This would be much better suited to [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @orthocresol Perhaps, but the MIT lecture was from a chemistry course. Do you think I should post this question in Physics Stack Exchange? If so, is there a way to move the question to Physics? Or do I need to create a separate, but identical question in Physics?

Comment: Why are lasers dangerous to look into? How do they work?

Comment: As each  photon has a certain energy, ($E=h\nu$ ) then the power /unit area is the number of photons striking that area per second, so intensity. (btw 'square law detectors' i.e. your eyes , photodiodes etc. detect intensity not amplitude. )

Comment: All those things are the same. You're mixing the wave and particle descriptions of light, so naturally, there are different definitions of intensity depending on the perspective.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about physics but is now too old to migrate.

Comment: @jonsca Really? 3-5 months is not "too old to migrate" I feel.

Comment: @Abcd It's a system imposed requirement.  We just plain cannot do it after a period of 60 days.

Comment: @jonsca I would rather blame it on the mods. After seeing so many comments that its about physics they should have moved it there. Poor OP can now not get an answer!